# Searching for text in log files with inputs from columns in excel

Tags: regex, excel, autoit, file-read

I am trying to use AutoIt for extracting text from multiple log files which are sized more than 500 MB and the text to be extracted is in an excel column. I'm having issues with FileRead which throws an error about memory. I've even tried FileReadToArray which I thought would make it easier for the function to process the huge string. All the files are collectively sized around 7.8 GB. The largest file is sized at around 800 MB.

```
  Global $aUserNames[] = _Excel_RangeRead($file,$Worksheet) ; Usernames need to be read from Excel
Global $sFolderPath = FileSelectFolder("Select Folder", "")
Global $aFileList = _FileListToArrayRec($sFolderPath, "*.*", $FLTAR_FILES, $FLTAR_RECUR, $FLTAR_SORT, $FLTAR_FULLPATH)
If @error = 1 Then Exit MsgBox(0, "", "No Folders Found.")
If @error = 4 Then Exit MsgBox(0, "", "No Files Found.")

Local $sRegEx = "(?i)"
For $i = 0 To UBound($aUserNames) - 1
    $sRegEx &= "\b" & $aUserNames[$i] & "\b|"
Next
$sRegEx = StringTrimRight($sRegEx, 1)

Global $Store

For $i = 1 To $aFileList[0]
    $sFileContent = _FileReadToArray($aFileList[$i],$Store)
    If StringRegExp($sFileContent, $sRegEx) Then MsgBox(0, "Info", "One of more users found in file " & $aFileList[$i])
Next
```

The code was assisted by jguinch in the AutoIt forum.

Comment: You could try using a windows version of grep or sed to search the files using the regex - https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/?source=typ_redirect Otherwise, you will probably need to read the files a line at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file one line at a time to avoid the memory problem.

```
For $i = 1 To $aFileList[0]
    $fileHandle = FileOpen($aFileList[$i])
    While True
        $fileLine = FileReadLine($fileHandle)
        If @error Then Exitloop
        If StringRegExp($fileLine , $sRegEx) Then MsgBox(0, "Info", "One of more users found in file " & $aFileList[$i])
    WEnd

Next
```